# why the number of irreducible vertical divisors on X is finite?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

I am reading Qing liu - gebraic geometry and arithmetic curves Page 356-358 8.3.3 contraction

On the head

he says the number of irreducible vertical divisors on X is finite 
,but I can't know why this is true..

plz help me[image][image]

Comment: Can you write a more precise question, including the hypotheses of the statement you are asking about? For example, what is $X$ in this discussion?

Comment: OK, much better. Now note that he says "Let $E_1,\ldots,E_n$ be irreducible vertical divisors" but nowhere does he claim that these are _all_ the irreducible vertical divisors. (Of course, they will note be.) He is just considering some finite set.

Comment: ok thankyou but I added a new picture . on this picture, he argue that for a proper set to be isomorphic the proper closed set has only a finite number of points of codim1

Comment: The passage you are now talking about has a different context. Now he is talking about a _birational_ morphism $X \rightarrow Y$. This is *not* the same as the original setup which was a morphism $X \rightarrow S$ from something of dimension 2 to something of dimension 1.

Comment: oh thank you..but i don't know still..anyway why have to be finite even in birational context